# With the second API call I get a 404 error

Tags: c#, api

I call an external web API in a foreach loop and pass an XML file to it. The first run works and from the second I get an error

```cs
xmlFileName = Path.GetFileName(xmlDocument.BaseURI);

httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);

basicAuthentificationEncoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(apiUrlUsername + ":" + apiUrlUserPassword));

httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthentificationEncoded);

requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlDocument.InnerXml);

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = apiContentType;
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;

requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);

response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

streamReader.Close();

httpWebResponse.Close();
```

I tried to switch to RestSharp but then I get the error 'Forbidden'

Comment: 404 means that the resource was not found on the server.  What URL are you requesting?  Does it match what you expect?  If so then it sounds like you need to check with whoever maintains the server.

Comment: 404 on POST, generally it when the creating resource has a link to inexistent resource.

Comment: Are you connecting to same URL every time or a different URL?  If more than one URL try putting 2nd one as first and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the resource i.e., URL is not available in the server.
Most probably, the your code is correct, but the URL you are passing in the 2nd run is not correct or is it unavailable. Could you please check and confirm that.
If they are different, then the issue is with the URL and not the code.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404?retiredLocale=de